# How to implement equal/approximate condition for double datatype in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table with one column of double datatype. I want to select rows by comparing against double value. If there is not exact value exist in the double column, I want to fetch rows containing double value which are equal or closest/approximate.

```
select * 
from tablename 
where DoubleColumnName equal/approx "some double value"
```

Comment: Column has entries to 6 decimal places ...it would be great if even 3 places can be approximate. For example, column has following value - 10.0000, 10.0001, 10.0010, 10.0100, 10.1000, and if I search against 10.0234 ...the query should return 10.0100 as it is the closest value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that with

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE ABS(DoubleColumnName-$value)<1E-13
```

here `1E-13` means precision delta (you can adjust it, of cause) and $value is searched value

Answer (score 1):

What is your approximation limits. Assuming you are happy with an error range of +/- 0.5, you can try something like this:

```
select * from table where (double_value_from_database - SOME_DOUBLE_VALUE) < 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) keyword

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE 
   DoubleColumnName BETWEEN "lowerBound" AND "UpperBound"
```